# My "Else If" Code Isn't Working As Expected

Tags: java

I am a new coder.  Working on an assignment.  This is also my first post here so I apologize if it's a little sloppy.

I'm having some troubles with my if/else statements in Java...the "if" conditions seem to work okay.  But my "else" conditions do not.  Take a look at the code and the build results below.

Basically, I enter an ingredient. And then I put in the number of cups needed.  And the number of calories the ingredient has per x cup.  That all seems to work as long as I input what I want to for "successful" results.

[Successful Build Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8obJc.jpg)

But when I start to input values outside of my criteria, my application doesn't seem to care.  If I input 0, I should get that output of "your response is invalid" or whatever it is I coded.  But it just seems to skip over that entirely.

[Bad Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqyVj.jpg)

```
package recipe_collection_manager;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ingredient {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Initializes the variables

        String nameOfIngredient = "";
        int numberCups = 0;
        int numberCaloriesPerCup = 0;
        int totalCaloriesPerCup = 0;
        double totalCalories = 0.0;

// Enter the name of the ingredient.

        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ingredient: ");
        nameOfIngredient = scnr.next();

        // Enter the number of cups needed for the ingredient.
        // If Else statements used to establish if the number of cups is valid.

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of cups of "
                + nameOfIngredient + " we'll need. The number of cups must be between 1 and 100: ");
        numberCups = scnr.nextInt();

        if (numberCups >= 1 || numberCups <= 100) {
            System.out.println("The number of cups is valid.");
        } else if (numberCups <= 1 || numberCups >= 100) {
            System.out.println("The number you have entered is invalid.  Please try again.");
        }

        // Enter the number of calories used per cup.
        // If Else statements are used to establish if the number of calories is valid.

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of calories per cup: ");
        numberCaloriesPerCup = scnr.nextInt();

        if (numberCaloriesPerCup >= 1 || numberCaloriesPerCup <= 1000) {
            System.out.println("The number of calories is valid.");
        } else if (numberCaloriesPerCup <= 1 || numberCaloriesPerCup >= 1000) {
            System.out.println("The number you have entered is invalid.  Please try again.");
        }

        // Calculation for totalCalories based on numberCups and numberCaloriesPerCup

        if (numberCups > 0 && numberCaloriesPerCup > 0) {
            totalCalories = numberCups * numberCaloriesPerCup;
        }

        System.out.println(nameOfIngredient + " uses " + numberCups
                + " cups and has " + totalCalories + " calories.");

    }
}
```

Comment: `numberCups >= 1 || numberCups <= 100` reads "if the number of cups is at least one, OR if the number of cups is up to 100 (or both), then do ...". Is this the logic you intended?

Comment: To build on what @nanofarad said. 0 is less than or equal to 100. So your if statement is true for the value of 0.

Comment: I see what you're getting at.  So the number has to be BETWEEN 1 and 100. If that makes more sense.  0 should fail, 101+ should fail.

Comment: correct. So check that logic to see if you've expressed your requirements correctly in your code.

Comment: The value is either valid or not; you want an `&&` (not an `||`), and an `else` (not an `else if`).

Comment: All integers are at least one of `>=1` or `<=100` (possibly both).

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in line:

```
 if (numberCups >= 1 || numberCups <= 100) {
 ...
 }
```

When you entered 0, program checked if 0 is greater or equal to 1, and that was false but you had also "or" condition ( || ), and in that condition you were checking if 0 <= 100 and because that is true, false || true gives true and that's why your if statement was correct. You needed to use "and" ( && ) instead of "or". There was flaw in your logic.

Test code below, it should work now:

```
package recipe_collection_manager;
    
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Ingredient {
    
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            //Initializes the variables
    
            String nameOfIngredient = "";
            int numberCups = 0;
            int numberCaloriesPerCup = 0;
            int totalCaloriesPerCup = 0;
            double totalCalories = 0.0;
    
    // Enter the name of the ingredient.
    
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ingredient: ");
            nameOfIngredient = scnr.next();
    
            // Enter the number of cups needed for the ingredient.
            // If Else statements used to establish if the number of cups is valid.
    
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of cups of "
                    + nameOfIngredient + " we'll need. The number of cups must be between 1 and 100: ");
            numberCups = scnr.nextInt();
    
            if (numberCups >= 1 && numberCups <= 100) {
                System.out.println("The number of cups is valid.");
            } else if (numberCups <= 1 || numberCups >= 100) {
                System.out.println("The number you have entered is invalid.  Please try again.");
            }
    
            // Enter the number of calories used per cup.
            // If Else statements are used to establish if the number of calories is valid.
    
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of calories per cup: ");
            numberCaloriesPerCup = scnr.nextInt();
    
            if (numberCaloriesPerCup >= 1 || numberCaloriesPerCup <= 1000) {
                System.out.println("The number of calories is valid.");
            } else if (numberCaloriesPerCup <= 1 || numberCaloriesPerCup >= 1000) {
                System.out.println("The number you have entered is invalid.  Please try again.");
            }
    
            // Calculation for totalCalories based on numberCups and numberCaloriesPerCup
    
            if (numberCups > 0 && numberCaloriesPerCup > 0) {
                totalCalories = numberCups * numberCaloriesPerCup;
            }
    
            System.out.println(nameOfIngredient + " uses " + numberCups
                    + " cups and has " + totalCalories + " calories.");
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: The inputs are either valid or not valid. I don't think the OP needs `else if`. It's a straight `else`. I also suggest calories could be zero. Water has zero calories. But that's more a requirements question than a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify.  The following statement

```
if(numberCups >= 1 || numberCups <= 100) {
...
}
```

Is true any number of cups.  Any number of cups `>= 1` will be caught by the first condition.  Any number of cups `<= 0` will be caught by the second condition since in that case they will all be less than `100`.  With a logical `||` only one condition is required to be true for the statement to be true.

In fact,

```
if(numberOfCups is >= A || numberOfCups <= B) {
...
}
```

will always be true as long as `B >= A-1`.